# Why long value is negative although it's smaller than Long.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java

The value of `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `9223372036854775807`
However, when I print the following:

```
System.out.println(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
```

I get `-1702967296`

Although the value should be `2592000000` which is smaller than `Long.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: use `1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30`

Comment: Currently you have an integer operation which overflows because result > `Integer.MAX_VALUE` this Erans solution is to be used

Comment: Thanks... I missed that :)

Comment: Or, better in terms of expressing the intent, use `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30)`. (Worse in terms of that not being a constant expression).

Comment: try use  System.out.println(1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L * 30L); or   System.out.println(1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30); java will convert to long value from smaller to bigger in second example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you are using are int not long. Use long value otherwise the result wraps round and becomes negative.